# How to write complex sed query which got special char

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I am struggling to replace a string with a special character. I am using the command below and I tried to escape each special character, but I am still getting an error.

If I don't use special characters, the query is working fine, but I have to use special characters.

String to find: `../../../profileone`
String to Replace: `@mysettings/future-system-one`

Query:

```
sed -i s/"../../../profileone"/"@mysettings/future-system-one"/g *.fileExtension'
```

I wanted to try this command from jenkins pipeline.

Comment: The issue is that your pattern and replacement contain the forward slash, which is also used as the default regex separator. Although you *can* make it work by backslash-escaping the forward slashes, it's simpler IMHO to change the separator. See for example [How to sed and replace string with a folder path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408960/how-to-sed-and-replace-string-with-a-folder-path)

Comment: ...and a single quote at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually have any special characters there, so you don't need to escape anything. The only issue is that you are using `/` as the pattern delimiter, so just use another character and it should work fine:

```
sed 's|../../../profileone|@mysettings/future-system-one|g' *.fileExtension
```

Note how the `sed` command is quoted, that is important.

Now, your question shows the target strings as `../../../profileone` and `@mysettings/future-system-one`, but your command also includes double quotes. If those are supposed to be part of the strings, use this instead:

```
sed 's|"../../../profileone"|"@mysettings/future-system-one"|g' *.fileExtension
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the comment by @steeldriver, you can change the pattern delimiters
from `/` to `_`:

```
sed -i s_"../../../profileone"_"@mysettings/future-system-one"_g *.fileExtension'
```

so that you don't need to escape all the `/` in this way:

```
sed -i s/"..\/..\/..\/profileone"/"@mysettings\/future-system-one"/g *.fileExtension'
```

Comment: Thank you, terdon and mattb
below two commands saved me:
sed 's|"../../../profileone"|"@mysettings/future-system-one"|g' *.fileExtension
sed -i s_"../../../profileone"_"@mysettings/future-system-one"_g *.fileExtension